# powerpoint interop chart.ChartData.ActivateChartDataWindow(); not working

Tags: c#, interop, powerpoint

```
chart.ChartData.ActivateChartDataWindow();
```

by using this statement powerpoint opens related data window for the particular chart but somehow for some complicated charts. this method is not working.why? and what is the solution for it.